# How to I webview login cookies in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, cookies, webview

My website has login control. If the user has logged in a different text, If the user has not logged in a different text.

I want to print on the screen.

Here is the code

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.Wview);
    assert mWebView != null;
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://arkadasimabakarmisin.com/");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
        {

            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName(\"page-wrapper\")[0].setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\"); " );
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            //

            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName(\"page-wrapper\")[0].setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\"); " );

        }
    });
```

Comment: you can get cookies from webview and maintain session.